# Mostrar resultado de un Web Service en un Label

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, webservice, aplicación-web

Tengo un Web Service hecho en Asp.Net que funciona bien, este esta conectado a una base de datos SQLServer que no esta en la computadora que contiene el Web Service, cree otro proyecto en Asp que es una sencilla web de consulta, funciona bien pero solo e descubierto como mostrar el resultado en un Grid, el resultado siempre devuelve dos campos de la base de datos [Precio y Descripcion] quisiera que estos resultados se mostraran en dos label separados.

El condigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Referencia.WebServiceSoapClient WS = new Referencia.WebServiceSoapClient();
        DataSet ds = WS.WSBuscar(TextBox1.Text);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Quisiera saber si esta es la mejor manera de hacer esto o hay otras mas eficientes.

Comment: Cuantas filas te devuelve el DataSet? Porque si son varias, como quieres mostrarlo en labels?

Comment: Solo devuelve 1 y 1, la funcion de la aplicacion simplemente es verificar un precio de un codigo de barra enviado, un producto a la ves.

Comment: En ese caso, revisa mi respuesta a ver si te entendí bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono a la perfección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te devuelve un `DataSet`, puedes acceder a cada columna por separado:

```
DataSet ds = WS.WSBuscar(TextBox1.Text);
Label1.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Precio"].ToString();
Label2.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Descripcion"].ToString();
```

O por el indice:

```
DataSet ds = WS.WSBuscar(TextBox1.Text);
Label1.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
Label2.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```